# How do I cache jQuery selections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, jquery-selectors

I need to cache about 100 different selections for animating. The following is sample code. Is there a syntax problem in the second sample? If this isn't *the* way to cache selections, it's certainly the most popular on the interwebs. So, what am I missing?

note: **p** in the `$.path.bezier(p)` below is a correctly declared object passed to jQuery.path.bezier (awesome animation library, by the way)

This **works**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        animate1();
        animate2();
    })
    function animate1() {
        $('#image1').animate({ path: new $.path.bezier(p) }, 3000);
        setTimeout("animate1()", 3000);
    }
    function animate2() {
        $('#image2').animate({ path: new $.path.bezier(p) }, 3000);
        setTimeout("animate2()", 3000);
    }
```

This **doesn't work**

```
    var $one = $('#image1'); //problem with syntax here??
    var $two = $('#image2');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        animate1();
        animate2();
    })
    function animate1() {
        $one.animate({ path: new $.path.bezier(p) }, 3000);
        setTimeout("animate1()", 3000);
    }
    function animate2() {
        $two.animate({ path: new $.path.bezier(p) }, 3000);
        setTimeout("animate2()", 3000);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the images are not loaded when you call them, jQuery will return an empty object.  Move your assignment inside your `document.ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $one = $('#image1');
    var $two = $('#image2');
    animate1();
    animate2();
});
// ... etc.
```

If you need to cache them for later use outside of your initialization script then add them to a storage object:

```
var my_storage_object = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $one, $two;
    my_storage_object.$one = $one = $('#image1');
    my_storage_object.$two = $two = $('#image2');
    animate1();
    animate2();
});
// ... etc.
```

Then later on, outside of `document.ready` you can call:

```
my_storage_object.$one //still has a reference to the jQuery object.
```

Comment: I used this solution too, but I wanted to point something out. I tried the code as above, and kept getting a syntax error on the line: var my_storage_object.$one = $one = $('#image1'); In the end, the way I got it working was to not to use var again with the following line: my_storage_object.$one = $('#image1'); I couldn't actually understand why the var was used again inside $(document).ready, but I am still a relative JS novice. Any idea why the above code might have had to be modified to work for me, or why the var is used again?

Comment: @CarvellFenton - the `var` is there to keep `$one` and `$two` (which are also being declared there) from being leaked into the global scope -- but that should be done separately actually.  I updated the code to be correct.  Thanks for that!

Comment: @Sean Vieira That makes sense to me now. Thanks for taking the time to update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
   var one = $('#image1');
   var two = $('#image2');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        animate1();
        animate2();
    })
    function animate1() {
        one.animate({ path: new $.path.bezier(p) }, 3000);
        setTimeout("animate1()", 3000);
    }
    function animate2() {
        two.animate({ path: new $.path.bezier(p) }, 3000);
        setTimeout("animate2()", 3000);
    }
```

fix

when you do:

```
   var one = $('#image1');
```

you're storing the jquery object returned by the selector in the var "one". So you don't need to use $ anymore.

Comment: forgot to mention i tried this. didn't work either. did you successfully test this?

Comment: `$one` is just a regular variable name, it has nothing to do with jquery. So changing it to `one` shouldn't do anything.

Comment: I thought so--it seemed most interwebs recommendations were to use $one as the variable name as a notation for "this variable, it jquery!"

Answer (score 2):

Also the variable declarations should be outside, but the selectors should be inside $(document).ready(), maybe those images are not ready yet otherwise?

edit, like this:

```
var one;
var two;
$(document).ready(function() {
     one = $('#image1');
     two = $('#image2'); 
     animate1();
     animate2();
})
```

Comment: if i make those declarations inside `$(document).ready()...` the objects won't be defined in the animate1() and animate2() functions. wait...is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var $one;
var $two;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $one = $('#image1');
    $two = $('#image2');
    animate1();
    animate2();
})
function animate1() {
    $one.animate({ path: new $.path.bezier(p) }, 3000);
    setTimeout("animate1()", 3000);
}
function animate2() {
    $two.animate({ path: new $.path.bezier(p) }, 3000);
    setTimeout("animate2()", 3000);
}
```

The variables are defined in global scope, but the selectors are executed when the document is ready.

Comment: I was just about to post this, but this one has the right solution.  The trouble is that your declarations for $one and $two are happening before your DOM is built.  Your code would work if you moved it to the bottom of the Body, but this code is another great approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selectors always need to be inside the `.ready()` block, so why not put *everything* there? That way you leave nothing in the global scope.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var storedGlobals = {
        $one: $('#image1'),
        $two: $('#image2')
    };
    animate1(); 
    animate2(); 

    function animate1() { 
        storedGlobals.$one.animate({ path: new $.path.bezier(p) }, 3000); 
        setTimeout("animate1()", 3000); 
    } 
    function animate2() { 
        storedGlobals.$two.animate({ path: new $.path.bezier(p) }, 3000); 
        setTimeout("animate2()", 3000); 
    }
});
```